# How would you prove this Big Omega complexity?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

We're given $f(n)=\frac{1}{5}n^2-30n-5$ and $g(n)=n^2$, and are asked to prove $f \in \Omega(g)$.  The exercise was posted, but no solution is given (this is not an assignment question).

So by looking at it, I understand that both are $n^2$ so it should be true, but I can't figure it out.  For reference, we use this to prove: $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists B \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq B \implies f(n) \geq cg(n)$.

Obviously (?) if we choose a small enough value of $c$, then it'll make $g(n)$ negligible, but how do we just choose it?

Comment: With more careful analysis, you can pick your $c$ and $B$ exactly to give tight bounds, but it suffices to show the existence of some $c$ and some $B$.  Let $c=\frac{1}{6}$ and $B=10^{100}$.  Then for $n\geq B$ you have $f(n)\approx \frac{1}{5}n^2 > \frac{1}{6}n^2 = c\cdot g(n)$.  Of course, my use of $\approx$ is not very exact nor justified, but you should be able to complete the argument.

Comment: Oh is that really acceptable?  I always thought that $B$ was just for edge cases, like when $n$ can't be less than 2 for one reason or another.  How would I justify just picking a very large value of $B$ over another one, for example?  Is there no way to mathematically manipulate a sort of $f=... \geq ... \geq cg(n)$?

Comment: As to how to choose it the value of $c$, you could have picked $c = \frac{1}{5}-\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon>0$, in which case you can pick your $B$ based on $\epsilon$.  More explicitly, the dominant term coefficients of each function should be such that the dominant term's coefficient in $f$ is bigger than the dominant term's coefficient in $c\cdot g$.  You are allowed to pick *large* $B$ since $\Omega,\mathcal{O},\omega,$ and $o$ notations care only about assymptotic behavior as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Oh.  OK.  I actually think I figured out how to do it using the course definition of limits (since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\frac{1}{5}$, then we can use $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq n_0 \implies \frac{1}{5}-\epsilon < \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \frac{1}{5}+\epsilon$, which would tie nicely into your suggestion for $c$.  Thanks!